# getSupportLoaderManager() устарело?

Tags: android

Ковыряюсь в своем приложении, решил внести обновления некоторые. Заметил такое предупреждение что `getSupportLoaderManager() is deprecated`. Я нагуглив нашел ответы людей о том, что загрузчики и вовсе объявлены устаревшими в API 28 и рекомендуют используют `ViewModel` и `LiveData`. А как ими пользоваться? Можно дать на примеры реализации?

Мне нужно в своем коде переделать вызов загрузчика.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements KidsAdapter.OnItemClickListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    ***
    final private static int LOADER_KIDS = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ***

        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_KIDS, null, this);

    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bundle) {
        return new MyCursorLoader(this, db, id);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        kidsAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        kidsAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

    static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {
        Cursor cursor;
        DBHelper dbHeler;
        final int loaderID;

        public MyCursorLoader(Context context, DBHelper dbHeler, int id) {
            super(context);
            this.dbHeler = dbHeler;
            loaderID = id;
        }

        @Override
        protected Cursor onLoadInBackground() {
            switch (loaderID) {
                case LOADER_KIDS:
                    cursor = dbHeler.getSongs();
                    break;
            }
            return cursor;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Это части Android Architecture Components. Серия [уроков на русском](https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components.html), конкретно по вашему вопросу уроки 2-4

Comment: По урокам общая схема работы понятна. Но не очень понял как применить для моего списка это все. Нашел такой вопрос на англоязычном SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45636997/how-to-make-use-of-the-new-system-architecture-viewmodel-livedata-with-cursorada. Т.е. получается что адаптер писать для RecyclerView больше не нужно?

Comment: Адаптер для  RecyclerView нужен. Насколько я понимаю, он сейчас получает объект типа `Cursor` от `MyCursorLoader`. Чтобы не переписывать адаптер, похоже, что самый простой вариант для вас получать `Cursor` от нового компонента `Room`. В интерфейсе `Dao` пусть тот же метод `getSongs` возвращает `Cursor` (урок 8 по ссылке @pavlofff) и передавайте его в адаптер.

Comment: Я переделал все под Room. Возникла другая проблема, которую сейчас пытаюсь описать в новом вопросе